# Can we have two type of alerts in an application?

Tags: usability, icons, human-interface-guideline, content, information

In my application, I have two types of information in the content
1.Critical Alerts
2. Alerts that require user attention - may be or may not be critical, totally depending on the need.

I planned to use the same alert icon, but in two different shades

- Red for critical,
- and Amber for caution

to represent the difference. Any thoughts on this.
Is that a good practice to have two different shades of alert icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t want to design with using just color if you can avoid it.

Having a combo of color plus form (a different icon) uses 2 levels of distinction.

You’ll find Material design can use a warning triangle vs an error circle

[image]

[image]

Now you have shape, which can be more powerful than color, so it can avoid color blind issues, poor displays, and contrast problems.

Another device I’ve seen in incident management software is priority represented by 1, 2 or 3 exclamation marks:

**!**, **!!**, **!!!**

Comment: Lovely idea with the shape. Less so the exclamation marks. Hard to distinguish and much too polluted by arbitrary usage elsewhere.